# "Object variable or With block variable not set" using Regular expressions

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I'm getting the error

> "Object variable or With block variable not set"

setting the function to the RegEx object, so the thing is that I need to validate a File name with those patterns.

I'm thinking that the `Select case` it's wrong too. I don't know how to solve it.

```
Do While xExcelFile <> ""        
    strPattern = GetPattern(newFileName)

    With RegEx
        .Pattern = strPattern 'error occurs here
    End With


    Select Case True
        'go to next loop if the selected file and this workbook has the same name
        Case xExcelFile = xWname
            GoTo NextLoop

        'filter by name pattern
        Case RegEx.Test(newFileName)
            Workbooks.Open fileName:=xSPath & xExcelFile 'open file

        Case RegEx.Test(newFileName)
            Workbooks.Open fileName:=xSPath & xExcelFile 'open file`

more operational code below
```

This is the function that searches the desired pattern, and I think its work properly

```
Function GetPattern(ByVal newFileName As String) As String
Dim strPattern As String
Static RegEx As Object

strPattern1 = "^([B]\d{3}\w{1,})"
strPattern2 = "^\d*\.\d{4}\w*"

If RegEx Is Nothing Then
   ' To speed the code up set the static RegEx object only once
   Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
End If

With RegEx
    .Pattern = strPattern1
    If RegEx.Test(newFileName) Then
        strPattern = strPattern1
    End If

    .Pattern = strPattern2
    If RegEx.Test(newFileName) Then
        strPattern = strPattern2

    End If
End With

GetPattern = strPattern

End Function
```

Comment: Don't put the next loop in the select case; leave that particular case blank, or set i=0 and then for the other operational code, if i<>0 then execute, otherwise end if and moves to next loop.  This could lead to issues with overarching with statements, etc.

Comment: It looks like `RegEx` is local to the `GetPattern` code, which is why you get the error in the calling code.

Comment: More to @Rory's point, provide the whole proc that contains the `Do While` loop - there are a lot of pieces missing that will help put the puzzle together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Case RegEx.Test(newFileName)` doesn't make sense.

It should be something like

```
Do While xExcelFile <> ""        

    Select Case True
        'go to next loop if the selected file and this workbook has the same name
        Case xExcelFile = xWname
            GoTo NextLoop

        Case GetPattern(newFileName) = "^([B]\d{3}\w{1,})"
            'file is pattern 1

        Case GetPattern(newFileName) = "^\d*\.\d{4}\w*"
            'file is pattern 2
```

Comment: Hi @Peh, thanks for your help, this works fine thanks you very much, but I that this could be more improved, o not?

Comment: @JoseChiesa for code that works already but you think it can improved have a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com